# Trigger a GitHub Action run when complete PR require approvals

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, pull-request, git-flow

I want to trigger tests through Github Actions when a PR completes code review. I have set Required number of approvals before merging to 2, but I couldn't find any relevant events in the documentation. I hope to trigger the tests when both of the two reviewers approve.

I have tried possible events already, but it's not work.

- `pull_request_review`: submitted
- `pull_request`: review_requested
- `check_run`: completed

Any help or explanation is welcome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [pull_request event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) and filtering based on the `auto_merge_enabled` activity type?

I am not 100% sure it will work, but worth a try. I think if you have made two reviews compulsory, auto merging will be off until approvals come in.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi Pol Piella, thank you for your help. Later on, I think that auto_merge_enabled could not meet my requirements, so I compromised and used the following settings for pull_request events:

pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]